# Create Unsigned Long Long from NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, nsstring, integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing and retrieving unsigned long long value to/from NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181637/storing-and-retrieving-unsigned-long-long-value-to-from-nsstring)

I am trying to create a unsigned long long from a string so I can use the value in elsewhere but not having much luck doing so...Here is what I am using to attempt this

```
-(void)unsignedLongValue{


NSString *theString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu", [NSNumber   
unsignedLongLongValue]];    

theString = [[_message objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"id"];    

NSLog(@"%llu");

}
```

If you have any suggestions or know of any good articles I would be very much appreciative if you could inform me! thanks!

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181637/storing-and-retrieving-unsigned-long-long-value-to-from-nsstring

Comment: To request support for reading unsigned values from NSString, please visit http://bugreport.apple.com and file a dupe of radar://2264733 against component `Foundation | X`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to do this,

```
NSString * theString = [[[_message objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"id"];

NSNumberFormatter * numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSNumber * number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:theString];

NSLog(@"%llu", [number unsignedLongLongValue]);
```

Comment: Thanks This is the correct way to attempt this !  I got it working with starting from this code! thanks

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
NSLog(@"%llu");
```

does nothing. You need to tell the log what to print, not just what type it is. Use this instead:

```
NSLog(@"%llu",numberToPrint);
```

Also, you re-write `theString` immediately after defining it, so the initial value from

```
NSString *theString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu", [NSNumber unsignedLongLongValue]];
```

is never used.

Comment: One more thing about the last part, instance method is being called on a class.

Comment: @Deepak: Yes, his code is a wash. Hence why I voted up your re-write. You might be kind and explain why your way is so much better.

Comment: These are all great responses! I appreciate the help, I am going to try a few things you suggested and will let you all know how things went! Thanks agin