# Problems converting NSString to unsigned long long

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing and retrieving unsigned long long value to/from NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181637/storing-and-retrieving-unsigned-long-long-value-to-from-nsstring)

Having problems trying to convert an NSString to an unsigned long long. Heres the code:

```
    NSString* mp3id = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:"16902439379132728577"];

    NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSNumber* persistentId = [f numberFromString:mp3id];  

    unsigned long long test = [persistentId unsignedLongLongValue];
    NSLog(@"unsigned long long is %llu",test);
    [f release];
```

Output:

2011-07-09 15:28:06.834 NBUnityMP3Plugin[443:307] unsigned long long is 16902439379132729344
2011-07-09 15:28:06.847 NBUnityMP3Plugin[443:307] persistant id is 1.690243937913273e+19

To make it clearner:

```
16902439379132728577 - input
16902439379132729344 - output
```

Ideally I would like to get that unsigned long long into an NSNumber variable. I figured that would be easy if I only had an unsigned long long.

Comment: To request support for reading unsigned values from NSString, please visit http://bugreport.apple.com and file a dupe of radar://2264733 against component `Foundation | X`.

Answer (score 2):

NSNumberFormatter is representing the unsigned long long as a float, and I thought setting `[f setAllowsFloats:NO];` after initializing the `NSNumberFormatter` would fix the problem.  It doesn't seem to do that, though (returning `nil` when trying to set the number).  It is possible that `16902439379132728577` is too long for NSNumberFormatter to handle as an integer, and it may only handle `signed` integers in the `long long` range.

Comment: Yes, seems like the formatter rounded it up in some way. Thanks for looking into it anyway.