# Storing and retrieving an int64_t from an NSDictionary: NSNumber vs NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, 32bit-64bit, game-center, icloud

I am developing a game with Game Center functionality. 
Internally, my game holds all scores in variables of type `int64_t`, since that is the required type for reporting scores through the `GameKit` API (I assume this is to avoid ambiguity between 32 bit and 64 bit platforms).

***So far, so good.***

Next, I wish to store the user's hiscore locally (say, in `NSUserDefaults`. But a .plist would be equivalent) for when there's no authenticated Game Center player, and also to sync it via iCloud key-value with other devices owned by the user.

I can ***store*** the `int64_t` hiscore like this:

```
// (int64_t) _hiscore is an ivar.
// (NSString) _playerID is the authenticated player ID, or else 
//  "AnonymousUser" when GKLocalPlayer is not authenticated.

[playerData setObject:@(_hiscore) forKey:@"HiScore"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:playerData forKey:_playerID];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

...(assuming the "@( )" operator will take proper care in all cases - not sure about this either...), but which `NSNumber` method should I use to ***retrieve*** the value without risking integer overflow?

All the `-*value` methods of the class (e.g. `-intValue`, `-longValue`, `-unsignedIntegerValue` etc.) return types that are platform-dependant (unlike int64_t, which has an explicit byte size). [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107544/types-in-objective-c-on-iphone) gives great info on all the data types on each platform, but it doesn't help with `NSNumber`...

I could do a runtime check of the sizes of the distinguishing types of each platform (e.g. see if `sizeof(unsigned long)` equals 4 or 8, and use a different method in each case), but that *doesn't look elegant*. Not that a new architecture will appear any time soon, but...

I could also store the number as a string, as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181637/storing-and-retrieving-unsigned-long-long-value-to-from-nsstring), but having the dictionary-friendly NSNumber at hand, it feels silly...

What would you recommend?

Comment: `[NSNumber numberWithLongLong]`. Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/64BitChangesCocoa/64BitChangesCocoa.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSNumber/numberWithLongLong:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `-[NSNumber longLongValue]`. C standard (C99) guarantees `long long` to be at least 64 bits.

By the way, the new `@(_hiscore)` syntax is equivalent to `[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:_hiscore]` if `_hiscore` is `int64_t`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do just that.

Comment: I just noticed that similarly, `-[NSNumber unsignedIntValue]` (**not unsignedIntEGERValue**, which returns an `NSUInteger`) gives you a 32 bit int, on both platforms.