# Objective C - Type Casting From NSString to Int

Tags: objective-c, casting

I have this bit of Objective C code, where I am casting a `NSString` to an `int`:

```
NSString *a=@"123abc";
NSInteger b=(int) a;
NSLog(@"b: %d",b);
```

And the `NSLog` produces this output:

```
b: 18396
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

I was under the impression type casting a string to an integer would get the numerical value from the string.

Comment: for getting numeric values from string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663438/objective-c-find-numbers-in-string

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You've got integer value of pointer to `NSString` object there. To parse string to integer you should do:

```
NSString *a = @"123abc";
NSInteger b = [a integerValue];
```

Answer (score 12):

To get the numerical value use :

```
int val = [stringObj intValue];
```

or for `NSInteger` :

```
NSInteger val = [stringObj integerValue];
```

Answer (score 5):

When you cast an object to an integer you will get the pointer to the memory address. You can call to `[a integerValue]` to get the integer value of the string.

Also when casting it is better to use `NSInteger` instate of `int`. Because when using a 64 bit operating system a `NSInteger` will be 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Or with Objective-C literals syntax:

```
@([a intValue]);
```

Comment: you get NSNumber* here, not NSInteger