# Convert NSString to NSInteger

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have

```
NSString *strAmount = @"10.00";
NSInteger totalAmount = totalAmount + [strAmount integerValue];
```

**The output is**

> totalAmount = 80

but I want the output to be totalAmount = 10

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C - Type Casting From NSString to Int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046047/objective-c-type-casting-from-nsstring-to-int)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert NSString to NSInteger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791470/convert-nsstring-to-nsinteger)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all `totalAmount` should not be of pointer type.
2. Variable '`totalAmount`' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization

replace your code with

```
NSString *strAmount = @"10.00";
NSInteger totalAmount =  0;
totalAmount = totalAmount + [strAmount integerValue];
 NSLog(@" %ld",(long)totalAmount);
```

> Output = 10

Answer (score 0):

why you did pointer to int?

```
NSInteger totalAmount 0;
totalAmount = totalAmount + [strAmount integerValue];
```

Comment: when i just ask quest..i made a mistake..sorry

Answer (score 0):

Replace `NSInterger *total` by `NSInteger total` or convert NSInteger to int (C based)

```
NSString *strAmount = @"10.00";

NSInteger totalAmount = 0;
totalAmount = totalAmount + [strAmount integerValue];
```