# Convert CLLocation String in CLLocation using swift

Tags: swift, xcode, location

I have a variable which contains a location in `String` format. This location is an ex `CLLocation` converted in `String` to upload it in my database. Then, this location looks like this:

"<+48.77516697,+2.27782000> +/- 65.00m (speed...";   (like a real `CLLocation` value but in `String` format).

I want to convert it back in `CLLocation` format.

I don't have any code at the moment because I don't know at all how to do this. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: A better question might be, why not convert it into a more useful string format to start with instead of using the debugging string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple way is as follows:

```
let s = "<+48.77516697,+2.27782000> +/- 65.00m (speed..."
let ss = s.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "<,>")).flatMap({
    Double($0)
}) // [48.77516697, 2.27782]
let c = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: ss[0], longitude: ss[1])
```

More sophisticated solutions should probably use `Scanner` (`NSScanner` in Obj-C) as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663438/objective-c-find-numbers-in-string). Alternatively, if you're feeling masochistic, check out `RegularExpression`/`NSRegularExpression`... :)

Comment: Thanks that works! ;)