# Split the Numbers and characters in the String

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want to split the numbers and characters in a string only if a string contains numbers otherwise I don't want to split it.

ex:

```
String1 = @"hai 1234";
```

I want to split the this string as

```
String2 = 1234
String3 = hai;
```

another ex:

```
String1 = @"hai"
```

I don't want to split.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to split `Characters` & `Numbers`

```
//Numbers

    NSString *numbers = [@"hai 1234" stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]];

//Characters

    NSString *characters = [@"hai 1234" stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate. 
[Objective-C: Find numbers in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663438/objective-c-find-numbers-in-string)

```
// Input
NSString *originalString = @"This is my string. #1234";

// Intermediate
NSString *numberString;

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:originalString];
NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

// Throw away characters before the first number.
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:NULL];

// Collect numbers.
[scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&numberString];

// Result.
int number = [numberString integerValue];

// Text
NSString *text = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:numberString withString:@""];
```

Comment: it i want to split numbers and characters ,not only the number s

Comment: So, after get the number string you can `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` to original string and get the text you want
`NSString *text = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:numberString withString:@""];`

Answer (score 0):

```
   //number 
     NSString *onlyNumbers = [[string1 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                    [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] 
                    componentsJoinedByString:@""];

   //characters

    NSString *onlyCharacters = [[string1 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                                [[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```