# check the Numbers in One textField and print it in another textfield on click of a button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

There are two text fields and one button.

1st will allow any text value

2nd Will accept only numeric value from 1st input value, when you will click on Submit button.
Can anyone help me in doing this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective-C: Find numbers in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663438/objective-c-find-numbers-in-string)

Comment: Regarding [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434824/i-have-tried-many-searches-but-failed-to-get-the-exact-information-please-help), you can improve it rather than deleting it. Don't re-ask it, since the downvotes are locked into the delete question - it is better to improve it and then try to acquire some upvotes.

Comment: (As it is, all of your remaining questions seem to be broad design questions, and they are all at risk of closure. Please read the Help Centre articles to understand what sort of questions can be asked here).