# Scan for numbers in Objective - C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I wonder how could I able to find all the numbers as follows.

Input

```
NSString* input = @ "1m3s"
```

The desired output

```
@[@"1" @"3"]
```

I have tried the following approach

```
NSArray *arr = [input componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                        [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ms"]];
```

it returned me

```
@[@"1",@"3",@"@"]
```

Is there a better approach to solve this problem, any suggestion?

Even though this question has been marked as a duplication, I have tested the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663438/objective-c-find-numbers-in-string) but did not work.

**Update**

That could be any string value.

if input is `@"11m32s"` or `@11m32` and then desired output would be `@[@"11", @"32"];`

if input is `@"11x32"` or `@11x32y` and then desired output would be `@[@"11", @"32"];`

Comment: Look at the NSString method `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` and pass the output from that to what you have already been doing.

Comment: I have tried , please see my updated question.

Comment: You want to get your numbers as an `NSArray`?

Comment: @nayem, yes I want numbers as an `NSArray`.

Comment: @Nirav, I have tested both approach in the given answer, none of them works. Feel free to test with given input. Please remove duplication.

Comment: hi hotspring, please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/45025228/4061501

Comment: What will be the output of @ "11m32s"  this string?

Comment: Then output will be `[11, 32]`

Comment: @hotspring I have removed the duplicate request and added solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective-C: Find numbers in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663438/objective-c-find-numbers-in-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
NSString* input = @ "1m3s";
NSCharacterSet *nonDigitCharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
NSArray *outArray = [input componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonDigitCharacterSet];
outArray = [outArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length > 0"]];
```

Comment: If the input `[11m32s]` then it fails. The desired output `[11, 32]`. I have upvoted your effort.

Comment: Thank you! But when I input `[11m32s]`, I got result Array: (
    11,
    32
) with the same code

Comment: I also tested for `11m32s` & `11m32` and got ( 11, 32 )  when I log the result array

Answer (score 3):

Using a NSScanner would allow you to scan floats as well. In addition your array is populated directly with NSNumber instead of NSString.

```
NSString * input = @ "12m32s";
NSScanner * aScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:input];
NSInteger aInt;
NSMutableArray * result = [NSMutableArray array];
while (!aScanner.isAtEnd)
{
    if ([aScanner scanInteger:&aInt])
    {
        [result addObject:@(aInt)];
    }
    if (!aScanner.isAtEnd)
    {
        aScanner.scanLocation += 1;
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

Comment: This is a much better solution.

Answer (score 1):

To extract numbers you can use Regular Expression.

```
NSString* input = @ "1m3s";
NSString *pattern = @"\\d+"; // searches for one or more digits
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:input options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, input.length)];
NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    [result addObject: [input substringWithRange:match.range]];
}
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Or if you want to be more specific and extract the numbers in an expression `##m##s` use

```
NSString* input = @ "1m3s";
NSString *pattern = @"(\\d+)m(\\d+)s";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:input options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, input.length)];
if (match) {
    NSArray *result = @[[input substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]], [input substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:2]]];
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
}
```

Comment: what if input is `@"11x32"` or `@11x32y` as I mentioned in the question it can be any character?

Comment: The first version covers both. It considers any occurrence of one or more digits in a string.

Comment: Using RegEx is totally overkill and slow. Just use NSScanner.

Answer (score 0):

I think's it's helpful for you below the code work for me.

```
NSString *originalString = @"1m3s";
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<[originalString length]; i++) {
        if (isdigit([originalString characterAtIndex:i])) {
            NSMutableString *strippedString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:10];
            [strippedString appendFormat:@"%c",[originalString characterAtIndex:i]];
            [arr addObject:strippedString];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",arr.description);
```

Comment: The use of `%c` will only work for ASCII (8-bit) characters. But `characterAtIndex` returns 16-bit characters. At least use `%C`.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

```
 NSCharacterSet *nonDigitCharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
 NSArray *outArray = [[input componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonDigitCharacterSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Comment: the output is not `NSArray`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this handy approach:

```
+ (NSArray *)extractNumberFromText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSCharacterSet *nonDigitCharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    NSMutableArray *numberArray = [[text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonDigitCharacterSet]mutableCopy];
    [numberArray removeObject:@""];
    return numberArray;
}
```

Comment: That also returns me `@[@"1",@"3",@"@"]`

Comment: Nope. If you have non digit character at the last then you will get an `empty` string. Removing the empty one from the array will get you the numbers only.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to get your desire output:

```
  NSString* input = @"1m3s";

        NSString *newString = [[input componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                                [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
                               componentsJoinedByString:@""];


        NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i = 0; i < [newString length]; i++) {
            NSString *ch = [newString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
            [array addObject:ch];
        }


        NSLog(@"%@",array.description);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this code bellow.

```
NSString * String = @"24fsd35rf";
NSArray* Array = [String componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                              [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
NSLog(@"%@",[Array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self <> ''"]]);
```