# Copying a number from native contacts gives weird results

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I copied a number from native addressbook and it has possibly UTF-8 characters in the beginning and the end

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"‭+488778689898‬";
NSLog(@"phonenumber.length --> %lu", (unsigned long)phoneNumber.length); //Prints 15
BOOL hasPlusPrefix = [phoneNumber hasPrefix:@"+"];
NSLog(@"hasPrefix -->%d", hasPlusPrefix); // Prints 0
```

When I debugged the number using the debugger it shows 
[image]

How do i remove the character in the front and at the end from my NSString.?

Thanks

Comment: Possible copy of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663438/objective-c-find-numbers-in-string
Try to remove letter from string and save only numbers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27306065/1278744

Comment: I am not understand this How do i remove the character in the front and at the end from my NSString.?

Comment: what have you tried so far to remove those characters?

Comment: I tried to remove the additional characters by 
phoneNumber = [phoneNumber stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codes you see in your string are for dealing with text direction. `\U202d` is the "LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE" character and `\U202c` is the "POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING" character.

You can't remove them using `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet` since they are not whitespace. But they are control codes and they can be removed using `controlCharacterSet`.

```
phoneNumber = [phoneNumber stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet controlCharacterSet]];
```