# How to convert values from NSString to NSInteger

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsinteger

I am new to iPhone development.

I would like to fetch records from a database using the procedure mentioned below.

But when I passed the searched value of `searchDbAuthorId1 or searchDbQuoteId` to a method, it showed a `BAD ACCESS` message.

```
if(sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select distinct(qot.id), key.Authorid,  key.Keyword, qot.Quotes from Keywords key inner JOIN Quotes qot on key.Authorid=qot.AuthorID where key.Keyword like \'%@\'",dataSearch];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSString *searchDbAuthorId1 =  [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                NSString *searchDbQuoteId1 =  [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
                NSString *searchDbKeyword1 =  [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                NSString *searchDbQuote1 =  [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];

                terms *Objterm = [[terms alloc] init];
                Objterm->searchDbQuoteId = searchDbQuoteId1;
                Objterm->searchDbAuthorId = searchDbAuthorId1; 
                Objterm->searchDbKeyword = searchDbKeyword1;
                Objterm->searchDbQuote = searchDbQuote1;

                NSLog(@"searchDbQuoteId = %@",Objterm->searchDbQuoteId);
                NSLog(@"searchDbAuthorId = %@",Objterm->searchDbAuthorId);
                NSLog(@"searchDbKeyword= %@",Objterm->searchDbKeyword);
                NSLog(@"searchDbQuote= %@",Objterm->searchDbQuote);

                NSLog(@"searchDbQuoteId = %d",Objterm->searchDbQuoteId);
                NSLog(@"searchDbAuthorId = %d",Objterm->searchDbAuthorId);
```

I used `NSLOG` to know the actual values.

Following are the values with `%@`

These are the correct values I needed

```
2011-12-12 23:03:50.612 Quotes[1039:207] searchDbQuoteId = 15
2011-12-12 23:03:50.988 Quotes[1039:207] searchDbAuthorId = 6
```

and values with `%d`

and I am getting these values

```
2011-12-12 23:03:52.332 Quotes[1039:207] searchDbQuoteId = 109590272
2011-12-12 23:03:53.580 Quotes[1039:207] searchDbAuthorId = 109607456
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert first number in an NSString into an Integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138759/convert-first-number-in-an-nsstring-into-an-integer)

Answer (score 4):

Your question doesn't really makes sense to me, we'd need more information but I see you already tracked down the problem. So, answering your title:

> How to convert values from Nsstring to NSinteger

You can use the [`-integerValue`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/integerValue) method of NSString.

```
NSInteger integer = [string integerValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

`NSInteger myInt = [myString intValue];` is the answer to the title of your question. The questions contents, however, are not very clear and I'm unsure of what you are asking.